# Tips on designing a .NET API for future use with F#

Tags: .net, f#, api-design

I'm in the process of designing a .NET API to allow developers to create RoboCup agents for the [3D simulated soccer league](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RoboCup_3D_Soccer_Simulation_League).

I'm pretty happy with how the API work with C# code, however I would like to use this project to improve my F# skill (which is currently based on reading rather than practice).

So I would like to ask what kinds of things I should consider when designing an API that is to be consumed by both C# and F# code.

Some points.

- I make fairly heavy use of matrix and vector math.  These are currently immutable classes/structs.
- The API currently defines a few interfaces with the consumer implements (eg: `IAgent`), using instances of their implementations (eg: `MyAgent`) to construct other API classes (eg: `new Client(myAgent)`).
- The API fires events.
- The API exposes a few delegate types.
- The API includes several enums.

I'd like to release a version of the API as soon as possible and don't want to make major changes to it later if I realise it's too difficult to work with from F#.  Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best advice is probably to try using the API from F#.  :)

That said, I think what you have sounds fine

- any good C# API should be a pretty good F# API
- there's a little friction when using delegates/`Func`/`Action` at the boundary, but there's nothing you would change here
- enums, events, interfaces, classes, structs are all fine
- if possible, do avoid APIs that return values that are typically ignored (e.g. fluent interfaces that 'return this' to be able to 'chain calls' - these cause F# to need lots of `|>ignore`s)

But really, take an hour and try writing an F# consumer of the library.  In all likelihood, in the worst case, you might suggest a few helper functions or extension methods for F# to smooth over any friction points at the interface boundary, but I think what you have should all just be fine.

Comment: Thanks Brian.  Some useful tips there.  I'll give it a go from F# too, but in my experience of programming it takes quite a lot of exposure to work out what really works well and what doesn't.  I'm quite new to F#, hence the question.

Comment: Yes; if you can enlist one F# user to try it out, it may help (or give more confidence).  It's hard to get any software (including APIs) exactly right without having tested it with at least one 'target user' of the software to get usability feedback.